# how to append two dataframes with different column names and avoid columns with nan values

Tags: python, pandas

```
xyarr= [[0,1,2],[1,1,3],[2,1,2]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(xyarr, columns=['a', 'b','c'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['text','text2']], columns=['x','y'])

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

`df3` will have `NaN` values, from the empty columns a b c.

```
     a    b    c     x      y
0  0.0  1.0  2.0   NaN    NaN
1  1.0  1.0  3.0   NaN    NaN
2  2.0  1.0  2.0   NaN    NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  text  text2
```

I want to save `df3` to a csv, but without the extra commas
any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output? Do you want to have 5 coumns but you do not want commas when there is no value? This might be possible but is not valid for csv

Answer (score 1):

As  `pd.concat` is an outer join by default, you will get the `NaN` values from the empty columns a b c.   If you use other Pandas function e.g. [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) which is left join by default, you can get around the problem here.

You can try using [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), as follows:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2)
```

Result:

```
print(df3)

   a  b  c     x      y
0  0  1  2  text  text2
1  1  1  3   NaN    NaN
2  2  1  2   NaN    NaN
```